# Homestead can't see installed Vagrant Box

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

Laravel Homestead can't see the Vagrant Box even though it's already been added, and it tries to download it again. I deleted temporary files. If I try to add it again manually, if fails because it's already installed

```
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
box: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
This box can work with multiple providers! The providers that it can work
with are listed below. Please review the list and choose
the provider you will be working with.
1) hyperv
2) parallels
3) virtualbox
4) vmware_desktop
Enter your choice: 3
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v2.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
The box you're attempting to add already exists. Remove it before
adding it again or add it with the `--force` flag.
Name: laravel/homestead
Provider: virtualbox
Version: 2.0.0
```

When running homestead up:

```
homestead up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: < 0.4.0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
==> default: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.3.3) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.3.3/providers/virtualbox.box
    default: Progress: 0% (Rate: 0/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
```

How can I make homestead see that this box is already installed?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what's happening: when you do the `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` command, it will download the current release version (in this case 2.0.0). However when you bring up the Vagrant VM it appears to be looking for a specific older version 0.3.3. After both steps if you do a `vagrant box list` you will probably see both versions.

I'm not too familiar with Homestead but I'm guessing you are on an older version of the project and it needs an older version of the vagrant box.

If you want to download the specific version of the box, you can do so like this:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead --box-version 0.3.3
```